# How to update an "array of objects" with Firestore and Firebase functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, object, google-cloud-firestore

I have some body data coming into firebase functions as a array `['123','hello','34']`

I then process it by doing `const data = JSON.stringify(['123','hello','34'])`

After i update the firestore data by doing a set

`set({testData : firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(data)})`

Problem is, the entire thing is saved as string in firestore

```
testData: "['123','hello','34']"
```

Instead of an array.

```
testData: 
 0: "123"
 1: "hello"
 2: "34"
```

My question is how do i get firestore to save it as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting it to a string by using `stringify()`. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
docRef.set({ testData : firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...data) })
// use spread operator here                             ^^^
```

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#node.js_11) (NodeJS) has an example on adding multiple values using `arrayUnion`.

Comment: Nice, so i didn't need to do any conversions, thanks heaps !